# UML class responsibility distribution

Tags: java, oop, uml

My assignment is to design a parking meter machine and vehicles that can park and pay for the machine. There are also some other classes such as police to give out tickets and attendant to empty money from the meter machine.

[image]

I designed a Balance class to store money for the parking meter in a composition relation. When the attendant comes, it empties the balance inside the meter class. Here comes the problem: In OOP, we make all data fields private. Therefore, the only way to empty the balance in the parking meter is to either implement a "getBalanceObject" method or "emptyBalance" method in the parking meter class. However, because data field in Balance class is also private, I need to create another "emptyBalance" class in the Balance class. I also need to create a "emptyBalance" method in the Attendant class to fulfill its responsibility to empty balance from parking meter.

As a result, because all data fields in all classes are private, to modify a class which is inside another class as a data field. I need to create a chain of set methods in each class. It seems really stupid to do so. Is there any other technique to overcome this dilemma?

Comment: Any chance you can move that image here?

Comment: It has been added. I thought I didn't have enough reputation to upload an image.

Comment: The composite connector is drawn the wrong way. See http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_11/column5/images/fig1.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_11/column5/&h=176&w=434&tbnid=LLYgsTy25HfVxM:&zoom=1&tbnh=90&tbnw=222&usg=__UT4SA3_PCXpLM5fjNcQdWV2xaTk=&docid=Imoo9Jwo1OZDUM&client=safari&sa=X&ei=3eXpVJSUAY_bapa5gZgM&ved=0CC4Q9QEwAg

Comment: I don't see a dilemma. It's all about encapsulation. You can define getter/setter for properties which might help. You could use a stereotype to mark a property as getter/setter.